# Is there any way to close mail smtp session?

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

I am using Gmail STMP server to send emails. It works just fine. But since few days, it sometimes stops working. Now, it is only working 5 out of 10 times.

> Exception: `Failure Sending Email`
>
> Inner Exception: `Unable to connect to remote server.`

After talking to hosting technical support, they said there is a mail session limit on their server. This is a "Shared Hosting", so when it exceeds all new connections are blocking. They said they are trying to fix it. But also said please check that you are "closing the mail session properly or not".

I looked into it, but there is no `Close()` or `Dispose()`. I also read there is no acknowledgement for SMTP tranfer?

Please let me know if there is anyway to close the mail session? Or any workaround to fix this issue.

I am using `System.Net.Mail`:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
NetworkCredential info = new NetworkCredential("email", "password");
```

Then there is another method which calls `sc.Send()`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) implements `IDisposable`, so I would suggest you use that. Use a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) block to ensure it gets correctly disposed of.

Note particularly that use of `System.Web.Mail` is deprecated in favour of `System.Net.Mail`.

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.google.com")) 
{

}
```

You are using `System.Net.Mail`. In that case, you will find that the SMTPClient *does* have a [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706941.aspx) method (as it implements `IDisposable`), which will gracefully close the SMTP connection. However, it is considered better practice to use a `using` block, rather than calling `Dispose` directly. Finally, please note the following from the linked documentation:

> The SmtpClient class has no Finalize
> method. So an application must call
> Dispose to explicitly free up
> resources.
>
> The Dispose method iterates through
> all established connections to the
> SMTP server specified in the Host
> property and sends a QUIT message
> followed by gracefully ending the TCP
> connection. The Dispose method also
> releases the unmanaged resources used
> by the underlying Socket.

Comment: IDisposeable was not added until version 4.0